How to detach a piped command from the terminal?
I want to allow the leading program(s) to operate in a standard manner and detach from the terminal once a graphical application launches. In this example fzf reads paths from a file, feeds the selected files and folders to the mpv media player:
fzf < paths.txt | mpv --playlist=-

When & is added to the command fzf never launches interactively:
fzf < paths.txt | mpv --playlist=- &

While mpv has a --terminal=no flag, it merely disables the terminal input and output, still leaving the mpv process attached.

[...] disables any use of the terminal and stdin/stdout/stderr. This completely silences any message output.
Unlike --really-quiet, this disables input and terminal initialization as well.


Hev you tried { fzf < paths.txt | mpv --playlist=-; } & or, if that doesn't work, ( fzf < paths.txt | mpv --playlist=-; ) &, to put the whole pipeline in the background?

You can make only the second command run in the background like this:
fzf < paths.txt | {mpv --playlist=- & :; }.
The : is a nop command which is used here because & expects another command in this case

@arielmarcovitch fzf < paths.txt | {mpv --playlist=- & :; } — you appear to be missing a space in {mpv,  only { mpv works on my system (-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \}'`).

@user598527 That's true, sorry for that

@arielmarcovitch Mind posting an answer?

When you put the & after your command, it applies to the whole command, not just the second part.
If you want to run only the last part in the background you can do it like that:
fzf < paths.txt | { mpv --playlist=- & }

Note that this doesn't add mpv to the shell jobs list for a reason I couldn't find. But it seems fine for your use case.
